Disallow column update based on existing value
I have the sample table below



Student
Current_Checkpoint




John Smith
1


Jane Smith
3



To prevent erroneous updates or fat-finger en-masse updates, I want to enforce the following rule
For the column Current_Checkpoint, the value can ONLY be updated to the next integer.
For example, for John Smith, the next value can only be 2, and for Jane Smith, it can only be 4.
Updating John Smith's Current_Checkpoint value to 3 (or any value other than 2) should be rejected by the database.
I believe this would be an UPDATE trigger, but I would need help constructing it.
Also, would a check constraint on the column make sense, or no?
Many thanks.

Sounds like an UPDATE trigger, you can check if deleted vs inserted checkpoint differs by more than 1 and throw an error. The trigger syntax is very well described https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

To clarify the requirement, is it that the column needs to be updated to the next integer 100% of the time? Or only when that column is being changed at all? Like, what if the table had a third column (call it col_c) and I do update SampleTable set col_c = 'foo' where Student = 'John Smith';). What are your expectations around valid values for Current_Checkpoint?

Further, if it ends up being the "100% of the time" case, it sounds like you might be re-inventing rowversion?

@BenThul this question does smells like X & Y problem. Plus, those triggers don't stop a delete nor a multiple update of values. Pretty sure OP doesn't really need this

but I would need help constructing it help would imply you've had a go and got stuck... as it stands you're asking someone to write the entire thing for you.

@DaleK your helpfulness knows no bounds

Yes you need a trigger to enforce this. Join inserted and deleted on the primary key and throw an error if you find incorrect rows.
CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER CheckpointExactlyOne ON dbo.YourTable
FOR UPDATE
AS

SET NOCOUNT ON;

IF EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM inserted i
    JOIN deleted d ON d.YourPrimaryKey = i.YourPrimaryKey
    WHERE i.Current_Checkpoint <> d.Current_Checkpoint + 1
)
    THROW 50001, N'Must update Current_Checkpoint to exactly 1 more than existing value', 1;


@Yoav24 You're right, missed FOR UPDATE, but THROW does the rollback.

@yoav24 did this answer resolve your question?
